# Until loop not working to navigate Twitter search results using cursor in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I had code that worked, looping through pages of cursors until next_cursor == 0... but then I had some issues with other things and decided to go back to an earlier commit. Now I'm still using the same code, and it doesn't work. It sets @cursor to the value of next_cursor_str, but the loop returns nil and only the first page of results gets saved.

```
class FollowersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @cursor = "-1"
    until @cursor == "0"
      follower_info = current_user.twitter.followers(cursor: @cursor).attrs
      @cursor = follower_info[:next_cursor_str]

      follower_info[:users].each do |follower|
        current_user.followers.build(
          fid: follower[:id_str],
          name: follower[:screen_name]
        )
      end
    end
    current_user.save
    redirect_to action: 'static_pages#home'
  end

end
```

Comment: Don't add an update as a comment if it shows the solution to your question. Instead, add an answer, and format it correctly so it's readable. Also, provide sufficient explanation so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
follower_info[:users].each do |follower|
  unless Follower.find_by(fid: follower[:id_str])
    current_user.followers.build(
      fid: follower[:id_str],
      name: follower[:screen_name]
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: My Follower model validates fid uniqueness, so when it tried to build a follower that already existed, it returned nil. By setting 'unless Follower.find_by(fid: follower[:id_str])', I can find any existing user before I try to save them, therefore preventing a nil return.